# NAIP image convolution using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, image

I am new to image processing and coding and I am having trouble applying a lowpass and highpass filter to a NAIP image. I have practiced with Landsat 8 images with a successful output but I am getting a white/ blank image for the NAIP image. I tried searching for more GEE documentation on this matter but found very limited information.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
var image=ee.Image('USDA/NAIP/DOQQ/m_3110613_se_13_060_20190226_20190504').select('R','G','B');
// Region of interest for section with buffer of 2.5 km
var roi = ee.Geometry.Point(-106.4126, 31.7835).buffer(2500);     

Map.setCenter(-106.4126, 31.7835,15);
Map.addLayer(image,{},'RGB NAIP Image: Q3');

// lowpass filter parameters
// Define the low-pass kernel.
// This kernel creates a 7X7 square kernel.
var lowpass = ee.Kernel.square({radius: 7, units: 'pixels', normalize: true});

//Smooth the image by convolving with the low-pass kernel.
var smooth = image.convolve(lowpass);

//Display the filtered image
Map.addLayer(smooth, {bands:['R','G','B'], max: 0.5}, 'smoothed');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically set the `min` and `max` value of the bands when visualizing your image. See [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_visualization) for an overview of the functionallity of `Map.addLayer()`. An example for you 8-bit (0-255 values) would be:

```
Map.addLayer(image,{min: 0, max: 255},'RGB NAIP Image: Q3');   
//Display the filtered image
Map.addLayer(smooth, {bands:['R','G','B'], min: 0, max: 255}, 'smoothed');
```